# Zipline command line interface does not work after installation

Tags: python, zipline

After installing zipline with pip, I can't run:

```
zipline run --help
```

on my OSX terminal. It says:

```
-bash: zipline: command not found
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can import in Python you can run it from the command line with the `-m` argument::

```
python -m zipline
```

> -m mod : run library module as a script (terminates option list)